# Will cutting away root(s) of a tree growing under my basement floor kill it?

Tags: trees, roots, tree-removal

The tree looks like a Norway Maple to me, though that hasn't been verified. The small section of the root I found (there may be others close by) varies from 2-4 inches wide. While I'm not certain it's coming from the Norway Maple outside, it's the leading suspect given the sizes of the other trees. I'm attaching photos of the root, the Norway Maple and the other nearby trees (all in my neighbor's yard) along that side of my house.

The Norway Maple's trunk is about 3' in diameter and the root section under the basement floor is about 9' away, 5' under ground.

[image: root section in basement]
[image: trunk]
[image: canopy]
[image: nearby trees]

Am I right in assuming this root is from the Norway Maple? In this situation, would it be more prudent to cut down the tree before/after removing the offending roots?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you cut the tree down you don't need to remove the roots. They will die and decompose naturally in a few years. Assuming the roots under your house are in complete darkness, nothing will grow there even if you get a few suckers growing from the roots elsewhere in the yard.

Removing a substantial amount of the roots on one side of the tree without felling the it will make it less stable, and liable to blow down in the next big storm. That is probably not a good plan, for a tree so close to your house.

Comment: It's not a Norway Maple, the leaves are too small. Regardless, have the trre cut down and get the stump ground out. If you just cut it down, it will sprout new leaves and branches. It's not going to be cheap with a tree that large. I'd get a neighborhood landscaper to do it rather than an arborist if you want to save some money.